# window.onbeforeunload tips and tricks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'd like to create an `onbeforeunload` "You have made edits to the page. Stay On This Page, Leave This Page" jQuery plugin.

The plugin will need to:

1. Accept a containing element. `$(".editableFieldContainer").beforeUnload()`
2. Autodetect changes to `not(:hidden)` input/textarea/selects.
3. Prompt user to stay on the page if elements within the containing element have changed.

   - except if the page was submitted via form.
   - except if the page/user wants to cancel the changes, e.g., a "Cancel" link/button was pressed.

Something like this (but not quite, it is missing some features):

```
(function(){
    var changed = false;
    $.beforeUnloadCanceled = false;
    $.fn.beforeUnload = function(){
        $.beforeUnloadCanceled = true;
        return $(this).delegate("input,select,textarea", "change", function(){
            changed = true;
        });
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        if(changed && !beforeUnloadCanceled){return "You have made edits to the page.";} 
    };
}());
```

Is there already a decent plugin that does this?

Answer (score 1):

This could be what your looking for.

[jquery.wtFormDirty-2.0.2.js](http://code.google.com/p/wt-plugins/downloads/detail?name=jquery.wtFormDirty-2.0.2.js)

Comment: looks like that could do it with a little work...and the code smells like rotten eggs. But its a start. Thanks!

Comment: I just made a newer version. This looks better than the old one..

http://wt-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.wtFormDirty-2.js

Comment: thanks for pointing it out.. fixed now! http://wt-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.wtFormDirty-2.0.2.js

Comment: I'll mark this as the accepted answer...but first you gotta fix the select code. I don't want anyone in the future seeing this as the Accepted answer when the code doesn't work.   :-)

Comment: it is still not quite right. I'm putting together a fix now. i'll post it when i'm done.